# Getting data out of tags (BeautifulSoup)

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Brief explanation: I have a script which loops through elements of a page, then returns the data. But I want it to return data which is not in an element, but in order.

```
import argparse, os, socket, urllib2, re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
pge = urllib2.urlopen("").read()
src = BeautifulSoup(pge)
body = src.findAll('body')
el = body[0].findChildren()
for s in el:
    cname = s.get('class')
    if cname[0] == "work":
        print s.text
```

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="work">1</div>
    <span class="nope">tosee</span>
    <span class="work">2</span>
    <span class="work">3</span>
    4
    <span class="work">5</span>
    <span class="no">nothing</span>
</body>
```

It prints 1235 and misses out the 4, but I'd like it to print 12345

Answer (score 1):

Simply:

```
print soup.find('body').text
```

Comment: The point is, just get the parent tag and you should be fine.

Comment: Because I only want it to show with "work" class along with not in an element (there'll be other elements too)

Comment: I have updated the HTML part to what I'm talking about.

Comment: Well, i think that wouldn't be very easy. You'll need someone who is good at handling regex (which i'm not very fond of). Datas in HTML document _should_ be inside a tag, or things will mess up. BS wasn't meant to parse something like this.

Answer (score 0):

I formatted your html with line breaks to help show why 4 is not printing where you would expect.

You are iterating through the children of  and printing the text from any children that are of the class "work".  The number 4 does not fit this criteria, because it is the text of , not a child with a class of "work".

I don't think BeautifulSoup can decode this particular html as you would expect it to.

One solution would be to parse the html yourself, since this isn't a typical situation.  One way might be to use regex to find instances of something like:

```
</span>(not_blank)<span class="{classregex}">(remember)</span>
```

Build a dictionary of {remember: not_blank}.  Then as you loop through body.children(), validate s.text() against this dictionary.  If it is a key, print the value, then print s.text().

Depending on what the actual html is this might work...

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
arr = []
# Get all text elements
for i in body[0].find_all(text=True):
  # append to array if it's 'work' element or has no class
  if not i.parent.has_attr("class") or "work" in i.parent["class"]:
    arr.append(i)
```

This of course only works if following two rules are always valid:

1. a valid text element is inside a class="work", or
2. a valid text element is inside a tag that does not have a class attribute